# Flutter - go_router and navigation with query parameters

Tags: flutter

I'm building a simple web application with Flutter. Navigation is done using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router).

```
  static final routerConfig = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: Routes.login,
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: Routes.loginSuccess,
        builder: (context, state) {
          var code = state.queryParameters['code'];
          var stateParam = state.queryParameters['state'];
          return const LoginPage();
        },
      ),
    ],
    initialLocation: Routes.login,
  );
```

The routes are:

```
class Routes {
  static const login = '/';
  static const loginSuccess = '/login-success';
}
```

However when Amplify is returning to my callback with `code` and `state` as query parameters, but I get following error.

```
======== Exception caught by Flutter framework =====================================================
The following message was thrown:
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/login-success?code=hiddenCode&state=hiddenState"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.

====================================================================================================
```

Routing via

```
context.go(Uri(
          path: Routes.loginSuccess,
          queryParameters: {'code': 'myCode', 'state': 'myState'}).toString());
```

is just working.

If the application is restarted via the authentication provider I get the error.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Try `static const loginSuccess = 'login-success';`, without the slash. Actually you return the same `LoginPage` from both routes, is this intentional?

Comment: The slash prefix is mandatory for `go_router`. The error I get is `top-level path must start with \"/\": GoRoute(name: null, path: login-success)`. For now is going to the same page intentionally, until I get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was. It was caused by a FutureBuilder which was initialy returning an empty MaterialApp widget, without any routing. So make sure that your router is setup at startup.